# iframe embed code throws 403 error

Tags: php, ajax, iframe, http-status-code-403

I am trying to design a Content Management System (For blog). Everything works fine, but I have a weird problem about update section. Update section works with jquery-ajax and php. A jquery function checks the inputs, if everything is OK (not empty etc), sends all data to addpostup.php via AJAX (POST method). The problem is,

When I add the code iframe (for youtube link) on textarea, it throws

```
jquery-3.0.0.min.js:4 POST addpostup.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

On local host it was working perfectly. When I add iframe code without properties

```
<iframe></iframe>
```

it throws same error 403.

**The permissin 0755 have been granted to addpostup.php.** There is still same error. Additional I didn't add the code iframe, everything worked perfectly (also other HTML tags don't cause problem). My addpostup.php file is :

```
<?php
session_start();
require('checklogin.php');
require('../fn/db.php');

    $id = $_POST['addid'];
    $title = $_POST['title'];
    $image = $_POST['image'];
    $brief = $_POST['addta'];
    $text = $_POST['addta2'];
    $radio = $_POST['addradio'];
    $video = $_POST['addvideo'];
    $sample = $_POST['addsample'];
    $keyword = $_POST['addkeyword'];
    $descr = $_POST['adddesc'];
    $gdate = date('d.m.Y');

    try {
        $data = 'UPDATE tbl_cnt SET title = :title, img = :img, brief = :brief, textt = :textt, classt = :classt, videot = :videot, udate = :udate, surl = :surl, kword = :kword, descr = :descr WHERE id = :id
        ';

        $sql = $db->prepare($data);

        $sql->bindParam(':title',$title);
        $sql->bindParam(':img',$image);
        $sql->bindParam(':brief',$brief);
        $sql->bindParam(':ttext',$text);
        $sql->bindParam(':classt',$radio);
        $sql->bindParam(':videot',$video);
        $sql->bindParam(':udate',$gdate);
        $sql->bindParam(':surl',$sample);
        $sql->bindParam(':kword',$keyword);
        $sql->bindParam(':descr',$descr);
        $sql->bindParam(':id',$id);

        $sql->execute();

         echo('Success...');
    } catch (Exception $e) {
         echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }

    $db = null;
```

?>

database connection is located in db.php (included). My controller function (jquery-ajax) is;

```
function check_form2(){
    valid = true;

    $(".statusaddpost").html('');
    $(".addpost").css("border","1px solid #ccc");
    $("#addta").css("border","1px solid #ccc");

    if (!$("#addtitle").val()){
        $("#addtitle").css("border","1px solid red");
        $(".statusaddpost").append('<li><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empty title !!.</li>');
        valid=false;
    }

    if ($("#addtitle").val().length > 50){
        $("#addtitle").css("border","1px solid red");
        $(".statusaddpost").append('<li><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Max title length is 50. At the moment : '+$("#addtitle").val().length+' </li>');
        valid=false;
    }

    if (!$("#addimage").val() || $("#addimage").val()=='disab'){
        $("#addimage").css("border","1px solid red");
        $(".statusaddpost").append('<li><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Empty image!!</li>');
        valid=false;
    }else if ($("#addimage").val().length > 20){
        $("#addimage").css("border","1px solid red");
        $(".statusaddpost").append('<li><i class="fa fa-times-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Max img length is 20. At the moment : '+$("#addimage").val().length+' </li>');
        valid=false;
    }

    if(valid==true){
        if ($("#addvideo").is(":checked")){
            video="1";
        }else{
            video="0";
        }
        serdata = 'addid='+$("#addid").val()+'&title='+$("#addtitle").val()+'&image='+$("#addimage").val()+'&addta='+$("#addta").val()+'&addta2='+$("#addta2").val()+'&addradio='+$('input[name=addradio]:checked', '#addpost').val()+'&addvideo='+video+'&addsample='+$("#addsample").val()+'&addkeyword='+$("#addkeyword").val()+'&adddesc='+$("#adddesc").val();
        $.ajax({
            type:"POST",
            url:"../addpostup.php",
            data:serdata,
            cache:false,
            success:function(result){
                $(".statusaddpost").html('');
                $(".previewpic").slideUp(300);
                $(".addpost").val('');
                $("#addta").val('');
                $("#addta2").val('');
                $(".previewpic").html('');
                $(".addpost").css("border","1px solid #ccc");
                $("#addta").css("border","1px solid #ccc");
                $(".statusaddpost").html('<li class="addpostsuccess">'+result+'</li>');
            },
            error:function(error,e2,e3){
                $(".statusaddpost").html('<li>Error :</li>');
                $(".statusaddpost").append('<li>'+error+'--'+e2+'--'+e3+'</li>');

            }

        });
    }

}
```

Adding section completely same as update section (HTML structure, and process). Just SQL section is different. Adding section doesn't throw any error.

Also .htaccess file consists of compression and leverage codes.

I am waiting for your thoughts! Thank you for reading...

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand what the problem is, but I solved my problem. First I deactivated Apache mod_security (like server firewall) but didn't work. Then I did a simple encode and decode system. Before AJAX, I replaced it to a normal string. `JQuery replace()`

```
<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/randomnumbers"></iframe>

to

youtubevideo/randomnumbers
```

then AJAX sent the data to addpostup.php without error. Before update record, I replaced it to original string. `PHP str_replace()`

```
youtubevideo/randomnumbers

to

<iframe src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/randomnumbers"></iframe>
```

that's it.